# how to create a IComparable[] in c#?

Tags: c#, icomparable

```
public static void sort(IComparable[] a)
{
    int N = a.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j - 1]); j--)
        {
           exch(a, j, j - 1);
        }
        isSorted(a, 0, i);
    }
    isSorted(a);
}
```

Above is simple sorting code I found in book, the code is wrote in java and I try to translate it in c#.
Everything is fine, except how to pass the parameter.
Int32 is implement the `icamparable`, but how can I create a instance of `IComparable[]` and pass to the sorting function.

```
IComparable[] b = new int[] { 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
```

Does NOT work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to initialize `IComparable` with array of `int` you need to create copy. The easiest to write code is to use LINQ's [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx)

```
 IComparable[] b = (new int[] { 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 })
     .Cast<IComparable>().ToArray();
```

Note: normally you would use generics to write this the method - something like

```
 public static void Sort<T>(T[] a) where T: IComparable<T>
```